# Есть двумерный ассоциативный массив, нужно сделать из него одномерный

Tags: php, массивы

Даны дни недели:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [13:00] => "Франциск" Драма 16+
            [15:35] => "Вы не оставите меня" Драма 16+
            [17:35] => "Мистер Штайн идет в онлайн" Комедия 16+
            [19:20] => "Последний король" Драма 16+
            [21:00] => "Франциск" Драма 16+
            [23:35] => "Вы не оставите меня" Драма 16+
            [01:35] => "Мистер Штайн идет в онлайн" Комедия 16+
            [03:20] => "Последний король" Драма 16+
            [05:00] => "Франциск" Драма 16+
            [07:35] => "Вы не оставите меня" Драма 16+
            [09:35] => "Мистер Штайн идет в онлайн" Комедия 16+
            [11:20] => "Последний король" Драма 16+
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [13:00] => "Василиса" Драма 12+
            [13:55] => "Капитан Фантастик" Драма 12+
            [15:55] => "Моя большая греческая свадьба 2" Мелодрама 12+
            [17:30] => "Коко Шанель и Игорь Стравинский" Драма 16+
            [19:30] => "Ложные признания" Драма 12+
            [21:00] => "Василиса" Драма 12+
            [21:55] => "Капитан Фантастик" Драма 12+
            [23:55] => "Моя большая греческая свадьба 2" Мелодрама 12+
            [01:30] => "Коко Шанель и Игорь Стравинский" Драма 16+
            [03:30] => "Ложные признания" Драма 12+
            [05:00] => "Василиса" Драма 12+
            [05:55] => "Капитан Фантастик" Драма 12+
            [07:55] => "Моя большая греческая свадьба 2" Мелодрама 12+
            [09:30] => "Коко Шанель и Игорь Стравинский" Драма 16+
            [11:30] => "Ложные признания" Драма 12+
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [13:00] => "Василиса" Драма 12+
            [13:55] => "Супермозг" Комедия 12+
            [15:50] => "Вне разумного сомнения" Триллер 16+
            [17:40] => "Вулкан страстей" Комедия 12+
            [19:15] => "Доля ангелов" Комедия 16+
            [21:00] => "Василиса" Драма 12+
            [21:55] => "Супермозг" Комедия 12+
            [23:50] => "Вне разумного сомнения" Триллер 16+
            [01:40] => "Вулкан страстей" Комедия 12+
            [03:15] => "Доля ангелов" Комедия 16+
            [05:00] => "Василиса" Драма 12+
            [05:55] => "Супермозг" Комедия 12+
            [07:50] => "Вне разумного сомнения" Триллер 16+
            [09:40] => "Вулкан страстей" Комедия 12+
            [11:15] => "Доля ангелов" Комедия 16+
...
```

Нужно сделать сплошняком (что я только не перепробовал, ничего не помогает):

```
Array
(
            [13:00] => "Франциск" Драма 16+
            [15:35] => "Вы не оставите меня" Драма 16+
            [17:35] => "Мистер Штайн идет в онлайн" Комедия 16+
            [19:20] => "Последний король" Драма 16+
            [21:00] => "Франциск" Драма 16+
            [23:35] => "Вы не оставите меня" Драма 16+
            [01:35] => "Мистер Штайн идет в онлайн" Комедия 16+
            [03:20] => "Последний король" Драма 16+
            [05:00] => "Франциск" Драма 16+
            [07:35] => "Вы не оставите меня" Драма 16+
            [09:35] => "Мистер Штайн идет в онлайн" Комедия 16+
            [11:20] => "Последний король" Драма 16+
            [13:00] => "Василиса" Драма 12+
            [13:55] => "Капитан Фантастик" Драма 12+
            [15:55] => "Моя большая греческая свадьба 2" Мелодрама 12+
            [17:30] => "Коко Шанель и Игорь Стравинский" Драма 16+
            [19:30] => "Ложные признания" Драма 12+
            [21:00] => "Василиса" Драма 12+
            [21:55] => "Капитан Фантастик" Драма 12+
            [23:55] => "Моя большая греческая свадьба 2" Мелодрама 12+
            [01:30] => "Коко Шанель и Игорь Стравинский" Драма 16+
            [03:30] => "Ложные признания" Драма 12+
            [05:00] => "Василиса" Драма 12+
            [05:55] => "Капитан Фантастик" Драма 12+
            [07:55] => "Моя большая греческая свадьба 2" Мелодрама 12+
            [09:30] => "Коко Шанель и Игорь Стравинский" Драма 16+
            [11:30] => "Ложные признания" Драма 12+
            [13:00] => "Василиса" Драма 12+
            [13:55] => "Супермозг" Комедия 12+
            [15:50] => "Вне разумного сомнения" Триллер 16+
            [17:40] => "Вулкан страстей" Комедия 12+
            [19:15] => "Доля ангелов" Комедия 16+
            [21:00] => "Василиса" Драма 12+
            [21:55] => "Супермозг" Комедия 12+
            [23:50] => "Вне разумного сомнения" Триллер 16+
            [01:40] => "Вулкан страстей" Комедия 12+
            [03:15] => "Доля ангелов" Комедия 16+
            [05:00] => "Василиса" Драма 12+
            [05:55] => "Супермозг" Комедия 12+
            [07:50] => "Вне разумного сомнения" Триллер 16+
            [09:40] => "Вулкан страстей" Комедия 12+
            [11:15] => "Доля ангелов" Комедия 16+
```

Спасибо!

Comment: А что делать с дубликатами ключей?

Comment: `array_merge(...$data)` но ключи совпадающие заменятся.

Comment: Вот в этом то и проблема - все нужно оставить без изменений, как будто к первому элементу дописать второй, потом третий и т.д. Чтобы ничего не потерялось. Array_merge не помогает

Comment: то есть соединить строки? приведите пример значения для ключа `13:00`

Comment: Я бы сказал, соединить элементы массива. Ключи будут повторяться, - бывает что-нибудь на этот счет?

Comment: Повторяющихся ключей быть не может

Comment: Понял, что выхода нет, видимо

Comment: вы цель свою в этом действе скажите, может вам чего и подскажут.

Comment: Это тв-программа, как успели заметить. Мне нужно начинать день с 07:00-09:00, а тут постоянно начинается с 13:00... То есть, в array[0] - 07:35, 09:35, 11:20 идут в array[1] и т.д

Comment: Это называется flattern - вот хорошие ответы https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array

Answer (score 1):

Проверить он-лайн: https://3v4l.org/U5dib

```
<?php

function channels_flatten(array $channels): array
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($channels as $channel) {
        foreach ($channel as $time => $show) {
            $result[$time][] = $show;
        }
    }

    ksort($result);

    return $result;
}

$input = [
    [
        '13:00' => '"Франциск" Драма 16+',
        '15:35' => '"Вы не оставите меня" Драма 16+',
        '07:00' => '"Мистер Штайн идет в онлайн" Комедия 16+',
    ],
    [
        '13:00' => '"Василиса" Драма 12+',
        '07:00' => '"Последний король" Драма 16+',
        '15:35' => '"Капитан Фантастик" Драма 12+',
    ]
];

var_export(channels_flatten($input));
```

Результат:

```
array (
  '07:00' => 
  array (
    0 => '"Мистер Штайн идет в онлайн" Комедия 16+',
    1 => '"Последний король" Драма 16+',
  ),
  '13:00' => 
  array (
    0 => '"Франциск" Драма 16+',
    1 => '"Василиса" Драма 12+',
  ),
  '15:35' => 
  array (
    0 => '"Вы не оставите меня" Драма 16+',
    1 => '"Капитан Фантастик" Драма 12+',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Предполагаю, что вам нужна сортировка массива по ключам. Тогда решение будет выглядеть так:

```
// $array - ваш массив
$array = array_map(function($a){ 
    ksort($a);
    return $a;
}, $array);

var_dump($array);
```

В результате вы получите массив:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=11)
      '01:35' => string '"Мистер Штайн идет в онлайн" Комедия 16+' (length=69)
      '03:20' => string '"Последний король" Драма 16+' (length=48)
      '05:00' => string '"Франциск" Драма 16+' (length=33)
      '07:35' => string '"Вы не оставите меня" Драма 16+' (length=52)
      '09:35' => string '"Мистер Штайн идет в онлайн" Комедия 16+' (length=69)
      '11:20' => string '"Последний король" Драма 16+' (length=48)
      '13:00' => string '"Франциск" Драма 16+' (length=33)
      '15:35' => string '"Вы не оставите меня" Драма 16+' (length=52)
      '17:35' => string '"Последний король" Драма 16+' (length=48)
      '21:00' => string '"Франциск" Драма 16+' (length=33)
      '23:35' => string '"Вы не оставите меня" Драма 16+' (length=52)
  И т.д.
```

---

Если нужно ограничение по времени, тогда кроме сортировки понадобится какое-то сравнение:

```
// $array - ваш массив

const TIME = '07:00'; // Время начала телепередач

$array = array_map(function($temp){    
    array_walk($temp, function($name, $time) use(&$arr){
        $time <= TIME ?: $arr[$time] = $name;
    });
    ksort($arr);
    return $arr;
}, $array);

var_dump($array);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=8)
      '07:35' => string '"Вы не оставите меня" Драма 16+' (length=52)
      '09:35' => string '"Мистер Штайн идет в онлайн" Комедия 16+' (length=69)
      '11:20' => string '"Последний король" Драма 16+' (length=48)
      '13:00' => string '"Франциск" Драма 16+' (length=33)
      '15:35' => string '"Вы не оставите меня" Драма 16+' (length=52)
      '17:35' => string '"Последний король" Драма 16+' (length=48)
      '21:00' => string '"Франциск" Драма 16+' (length=33)
      '23:35' => string '"Вы не оставите меня" Драма 16+' (length=52)
    И т.д.
```